# Running PCA on all predictor variables in regression vs. running separate PCAs on groups of related variables

Tags: regression, pca

I am new to PCA and was hoping for some insight.  I  currently have a dataset with ~150 observations and ~80 variables, and the goal is to determine which of these variables are associated with our outcome of interest, using multiple regression.  Because of the large number of variables in relation to the small number of observations, I want to reduce the # of variables to place in the model.

Some of these variables can be grouped into categories (e.g. 10 variables relate to hospital staff training, 8 variables relate to equipment available at a hospital, etc.).  I'm wondering if I should include all of these ~80 variables into PCA and identify relevant components to include as covariates in the regression model (right now, this leaves me with 27 components that have eigenvalue>1), or whether I should use PCA to create scores for the groupings of variables (e.g. create a score for staff training, create a score for equipment availability), and use those as covariates in the regression model.

Another question is, if I were to take the latter approach of creating scores, whether it would be appropriate to run PCA on the resulting scores and other non-score variables (e.g. run PCA on staff training score, equipment availability score, sex of the staff, age of the staff, geographic location of the hospital, etc.)?

Comment: Welcome to our site! Thanks for posting such a clearly written first question.